# Which institutions are known to have been involved in Project MK-Ultra?

Tags: united-states, cia

Apparently, during the MKUltra project (the CIA's notorious research project into poisons, intoxicating drugs, drug-assisted interrogation and whether mind control was really possible, involving a lot of illegal human experimentation), the CIA funded research at more than 80 institutions, including hospitals, universities, prisons and pharmaceutical companies - not all of these institutions knew what the purpose of the research was or even knew that their backers were the CIA ([source](https://web.archive.org/web/20210330005628/https://www.nytimes.com/1977/08/04/archives/80-institutions-used-in-cia-mind-studies-admiral-turner-tells.html)).

Apparently, after the big scandal broke about MKUltra, the CIA claimed that they would notify all these institutions of who they had really been working for and which research projects had been related to MKUltra, but left it up to the individual institutions whether to reveal publicly that they'd been involved - or to notify the subjects of the experiments, many of whom had not been aware of what was going on.

It seems to be difficult to find information about whether the full list was ever released to the public.  Apparently, a few are known, e.g. [here](https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/politics/1977/08/18/3-area-colleges-used-by-cia-in-behavior-testing/b750e921-eda1-4e8d-ac99-de63edf2f6cf/), but I'm not sure how many others have been confirmed.  Which institutions, where there is reliable evidence, were involved, and what did each of them work on?